# Redirecting back to original folder Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I am creating a webiste in wordpress in localhost in folder wp1. The database for the website is wordpress1. I made a backup of wordpress files in wp2 folder and created a wordpress2 database.I also made a backup of database wordpress1 and restore the tables in wordpress2. Now when i try to login from wp2 in localhost like this

localhost/wp2/wp-admin/ it redirects me back to localhost/wp1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=...

I also changed the wp-config.php file in wp2 folder. I set the line 
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress2'); to wordpress2. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dado Yes you need to search and replace all the urls in your **wordpress2** Database

As you have import all the tables of **wordpress1** database to **wordpress2** so all the urls of is **wordpress1** db is  still there and stored in **wordpress2** database , you can see it in wp-options table .

so you need to search and replace db , search old url and replace with new url

you can use this file - https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

or you can use this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. I changed the column option_value to http://localhost/wp2 and now its working. Problem solved.